# Why can't I see all likes on a timeline post or photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

[image]

So in this image, you notice that there are 3 likes in this post. However, it only shows 2 names when hovering. Why is that the case?

I even clicked it but it only showed 2 friends.

Comment: I think you only see friends when hovering. When you click, you will see all 3 likes

Comment: Yup clicking the like should show you all of the likes.

Comment: Nope, clicking didn't work. Only 2 showed up.

Comment: The third person has you blocked? The third person has their activity set to "friends" only and you're not on their list?

Comment: It's a bug. Please [report this problem to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049/?ref=u2u).

Comment: Does the issue still affect OP? Has anyone else ever experienced this? If not can question be closed as unusable to anyone in future?

Answer (score 1):

You can. If the number of likes is not the same as the number of user profiles that you see after clicking on the number, either someone who liked it blocked you, you blocked him/her or they deactivated their profile.

Comment: If someone has deactivated his/her profile, there likes count also will not show. Wrong information.

Comment: if they have you blocked then how can they even see yourr post for liking it?, this happened to me also, cant find a reason

Answer (score 0):

The third person has you blocked? The third person has their activity set to "friends" only and you're not on their list?

But if you have someone blocked that person can't find you on Facebook. That person will not be able to see any of your posts that way so how can they like it? If that person has you blocked it's the same way; they can't find you on Facebook anymore/see your posts so they can't like anything.
I've tested all of this.

I have a post with 11 likes but only 10 people show up when clicking the likes. I have no clue who this person could be. The post, in particular, is set to Friends, it's not a public post.

Answer (score 0):

When your posts are audience selector "friends" and you find the number of likes different when you open to check, it is because the person who liked it and is now missing would have deactivated her/his account. When you check your friends list from your profile, you will find this person is still on your friends list but with no photograph.  If you click on the name, you will get the message from Facebook that the person's account was deactivated.

Answer (score -1):

They may have changed their "like" to something else.  I had someone "wow" a post and then undid it.  It still counted it - but since he undid it his name didn't show there anymore.